# Draw a 3D solenoid using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, latex3, asymptote

I am trying to draw a 3D solenoid using Tikz similar to the one here
[image]

But I'm having a big difficulty, I don't even know how to start...

Any tips, please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Tikz is not particularly good for creating 3D objects. Here it would probably be easier to use an external program and the result as an image.

Comment: @dexteritas Thank you for your reply. I have heard of Inkscape to be user friendly, I think I'll try it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an Asymptote solution with the module `tube`. I choose `brown+gray` for the color of the copper string. Feel free to change to another color, for example https://colorcodes.io/brown/copper-color-codes/

[image]

```
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
// adapted from http://www.piprime.fr/files/asymptote/tube/
import tube;
import graph3;
size(10cm,0);
currentprojection=orthographic(0,4,0,zoom=.8,center=true);

real x(real t) {return .03*t;}
real y(real t) {return .5cos(t);}
real z(real t) {return .5sin(t);}
real tmin=0,tmax=40pi;
triple A=(x(tmin)-.5,y(tmin),z(tmin));
triple B=(x(tmax)+.5,y(tmax),z(tmax));
path3 p=A--graph(x,y,z,0,36pi,operator ..)--B;
path section=scale(.05)*unitcircle;

// Define a pen wich depends of a real t. t represent the "reltime" of the path3 p.
pen pen(real t){return brown+gray;}

// Here the section has colored segments (by default) depending to reltime.
draw(tube(p,coloredpath(section,pen)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!